# Typescript Stateless React Component as named function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

Let's say I have a React component called Link:

```js
function Link(props) {
  return <a href={props.url}>{props.children}</a>
}
```

## How do I type this function without turning it into an arrow-function?

This doesn't seem to work:

```js
interface ILink {
  url: string
}

function Link(props: React.FC<ILink>) { }

// Property 'url' does not exist on type 'FC<ILink>'.
// Property 'children' does not exist on type 'FC<ILink>'.
```

But as an arrow-function it instantly does work?

```js
interface ILink {
  url: string
}

const Link: React.FC<ILink> = (props) => { }

// Compiles
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the combo `React.PropsWithChildren` and `React.ReactElement` so it becomes:

```
function Link(props: PropsWithChildren<ILink>): ReactElement {}
```